# AjaxActionLink opening a from(Ajax.BeginForm) in Dialog which is not refreshed when click on cancel and open a new link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dialog, asp.net-ajax

My view is sending an ActionLink which opens a Form in a Dialog

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Screen", "ExcQuestions", "Home", new {Student=item.StId, Formid = item.FormId}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "questions", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openDialog" })
```

In the same view I defined a div

```
  <div id="questions"></div>
```

My openDialog function is

```
  function openDialog() {
            $("#questions").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Exclusions',
            width: 550,
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true
        });
        $("#questions").dialog("open");
    }
```

and the other partial view which opens in the dialog is

```
@model IList<ViewModels.Questions>
<div id="questionsdialog">
    @using(Ajax.BeginForm("saveAnswers","Home", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="Post", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId="questionsdialog"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <table>
             @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].questionID)           
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsChecked)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].question)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x[i].StudentId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x[i].FormId)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button search button" style="margin-right:10px"/></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
        }
      </div>
```

Problem is that when I click on ActionLink it opens the dialog with questions but if i close the dialog(not submit) and click on a new ActionLink it opens the same old questions(dialog) again.The dialog doesnt get refreshed on a new actionlink call. Any idea....Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Omar..Thanks for the answer but after the change It doesnt display any questions in dialog..I put a breakpoint on @using(Ajax.BeginForm("saveAnswers","Home", new .........and on every new ActionLink click it does go for new question but doesnt display it in dialog...the dialog shows the old questions...If I refresh the whole page then dialog displays the new questions for the firrst time .....

Comment: When you say _"..click on a new ActionLink..", what do you mean? You have shown only one ActionLink - are there others?

Comment: @Stephen  ActionLink is in a table (in a different view) which displays a list of studentsand when clicked then displays the Partial View in a Dialog with list of questions

Comment: Cant see anything wrong with the dialog bit. Are you sure you are returning different result sets for each action link (based on the parameters `item.StId` and `item.FormId`)? Perhaps comment out the `openDialog` function to check what gets rendered in `<div id="questions">` when each action link is clicked